# Impala Query Editor always shows AnalysisException

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, impala

I am running a Quickstart VM Cloudera on a Windows 7 computer, with 8Go of RAM and 4Go dedicated to the VM.

I loaded tables from a SQL database into Hive, using Sqoop (Cloudera VM tutorial exercise 1). Using the Hive Query Editor OR Impala Shell, everything works fine (i.e. "show tables" shows me the tables that were imported).

Using the Impala Query Editor, whatever I type, I get the same error message:

```
AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: USE `` ^ Encountered: EMPTY IDENTIFIER Expected: IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY...
```

[image]

I have the same if I type "show tables;" ...

I checked that Impala-services were up and running and it was the case, and everything works fine in the Impala shell:

[image]

I googled around but could not find any answer, many thanks in advance for your answer !!

Comment: I think you need to first select a database in the drop-down on the left side bar, and then try and execute queries

Comment: I can't access the database: I should be able to do "invalidate metadata;" which would refresh the database list on the left and allows me to show tables, but entering "invalidate metadata;" generates my error ...

Comment: Could you go in the impala shell and type 'invalidate metadata'? Then retry in Hue and click on the refresh icon (little circle) in the Assist panel?

Answer (score 3):

Need to use the Hive Query Editor. The error shows up if you use the Impala or other Query Editor because you're using a library written for Hive.

Query -> Editor -> Hive

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try selecting a database and if one does not appear, try either clearing your browser cache and reloading the page and also verify that your user has permissions to view the default database. Although since you said that Hive query editor works fine, it sounds like permissions are not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue cleaning history from Firefox. After that i signed again on HUE and the databases on Impala Query Editor was showed again.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLrfB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Impala does not support ORC file format I changed to sequence file it works